# how to use d-inline-block

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

d-inline-block isn't working
I tried with css but still it is not working

```
<div class="d-inline-block">
    <!--Service Image-->
    <div class="service_img container d-inline-block">
        <img class="responsive" src="/img/service.jpg">
    </div>

    <!--Service Content-->
    <div class="container d-inline-block">
    <p> 
        Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
    This div is just here to enable scrolling.<br>
    Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.

    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you describe your issue?

Comment: what is the wanted result, what happends, please make a minimum working example.

Comment: service content is shown under image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use `inline-block` **use bootstrap's `row/col`**  (means use `flex` instead `inline-block`).

Wrap all in `div` with class `container`

Also and use [`img-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) class to `img`

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!--Service Image-->
    <div class="service_img col-6">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXoO.png">
    </div>

    <!--Service Content-->
    <div class="col-6">
    <p> 
        Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
    This div is just here to enable scrolling.<br>
    Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.

    </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

IF you want to use `d-inline-block` use as below:

**Set `width` to each `div**

```css
.w-49{
    width: 49%!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="service_img d-inline-block w-49">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXoO.png">
</div>

<div class="d-inline-block w-49">
  <p>
    Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect. This div is just here to enable scrolling.<br> Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.

  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: OP is probably asking for usage of `d-inline-block` class?

Comment: You can decide what to use(from the 2 options) but I think using `row/col` is better then use `d-inline-block`